# Regexp replace. Hashtag all words after "Tags:" delimiter

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

In a long file, using regexp in Notepad++, I'd like to replace every occurrence of  (space) after `Tags:` (with the column `:`) with a hyphen `#`, also deleting the commas `,`.

For example:

```
word1 word2 word3 Tags: communication, inspirational, love, relationships
```

should become

```
word1 word2 word3 #communication #inspirational #love #relationships
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Try `(\bTags:\h*|\G)(?!^),?\h+([\w-]+)` and replace with `#\2 ` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/16WQeJ/1)

Answer (score 1):

This regex will do what you want:

```
(\s+Tags:\s+|(?<!^|$)\G)\s*,?\s*(\w+)
```

The first part `(\s+Tags:\s+|(?<!^|$)\G)` looks for either the word `Tags:` or the start of a previous match (`\G`), where that cannot be at the start or end of a line (`(?<!^|$)`). The second part looks for a word, preceded by an optional comma and some space.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kvqFhF/1)

In notepad, bring up the Replace dialog, select `Wrap around` and `Regular expression`, and make the replace with string `#\2` (that's a space, followed by `#`, followed by `\2`).

Select `Replace All`.

Sample input:

```
word1 word2 word3 Tags: communication, inspirational, love, relationships
word4 word5 word6 Tags: single, mother, blue, sunny
```

After replacement:

```
word1 word2 word3 #communication #inspirational #love #relationships
word4 word5 word6 #single #mother #blue #sunny
```

**Update**

If you want to allow for special characters in the words (e.g. `-`) change `\w` in the regex to e.g. `[\w-]`. To allow any characters in the words, change `\w` in the regex to `\S`.

**Update 2**

As there may be lines which don't have whitespace before `Tags:`, it is necessary to change the `\s+` before `Tags:` to `\b`. i.e.

```
(\bTags:\s+|(?<!^|$)\G)\s*,?\s*(\S+)
```

[Updated Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/kvqFhF/2)

Comment: Thank you very much Nick. This is working fine, but the replacement is stopping where the array of words includes a hyphen such as word1-word2. ....would appreciate your kind help

Comment: Can that happen on either side of `Tags`? Are any other special characters possible?

Comment: @Markov see my update, changing the regex as I describe should solve your problem

Comment: Nick. I genuinely appreciate your help. I am sure there is a typo somewhere. NO, the hyphen and any other special characters are only AFTER the "Tags:". I tried replacing \w with \w- or \S, but again, "Tags:" gets removed, the FIRST word gets a leading #, and all other words remain ... see the example below:

Comment: Please try in Notepad++ with this example: <h2>…The wonders of life ...</h2><br>Tags: metaphor, science, string-theory1, string-theory2, string-theory3

Comment: @Markov no problem - but in future please try to put as many different test cases into the question as possible. Please see my latest edit and updated demo. It is working for me in Notepad++ 7.5.8

Comment: thank you much Nick. I really appreciate your kind help. To be honest, I needed that quickly, so as I realized I am having some challenges getting it right, I did the required change the old silly way of importing to excel, doing the changes and exporting back to text.

Comment: Fair enough. It's a tried and true method! Sorry we couldn't get it resolved in time.